# Estoy creando un código en PHP para mostrar tablas y sale error

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, tablas

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'artista ORDER BY IDart' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Conexiones\lee.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Conexiones\lee.php(6): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Conexiones\lee.php on line 6

```php
<?php
include 'ejemplo-conexion.php';     
/*mandanos a llamar nuestro archivo que conectar*/
$pdo=conectar(); /*Llamamos la funcion conectar*/

$sen=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM datos de artista ORDER BY IDart');
$sen->execute();    
$artistas=$sen->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); /* Aqui le decimos que hacer*/
?>
```

Comment: Tenés una tabla que se llama "datos de artista" así con espacios? Probá encerrar el nombre de la tabla con comillas simples ('datos de artista') o "backticks" (\`datos de artista\`).

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta esta mal escrita

```
$sen=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM datos de artista ORDER BY IDart');
```

El nombre de la tabla no debería tener espacios, podría ser asi:

```
$sen=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM datos_artistas ORDER BY IDart');
```

Answer (score 0):

el error es la siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM datos de artista ORDER BY IDart
```

en la cual el uso de variable con espacio lo que va a genere son solo errores, un ejemplo es -- **datos de artista** -- lo que el sistema va a intepreta es

```
SELECT * FROM datos
```

la manera correcta es el uso _ en cada separado o espacio

```
SELECT * FROM datos_de_artista ORDER BY IDart
```

pero si utiliza datos_de_artista, datos_de_obra , datos_de_ano , lo recomendable es el uso de palabra en **plural** o **singular**

```
SELECT * FROM artista ORDER BY IDart
```

El motivo de **plural** o **singular**. ¿Las tablas almacenan múltiples registros de User o Users? Queda mejor para mí Users y ¿cada registro tiene name o names? Pues creo que es más apropiado decir name. A no ser que el campo sea una key foránea entonces lo apropiado es usar pequeños identificadores que visualmente te ayuden a identificar que ese campo que tiene algo más que un dato simplón. Por ejemplo la tabla COMMENTS tendrá un campo user_id (no users ni id_usuario, ni cosas raras). Referencia de forma singular a la tabla foránea USERS e indica que ahí almacenas el ID, user_id

En las tablas intermedias, por ejemplo cualquier relación one to many como, por ejemplo, usuarios (USERS) y todas las fotos subidas (PHOTOS). Respeto las MAYÚSCULAS y uso el símbolo _ para concatenar USERS_PHOTOS.

En algunos casos en los nombres de las tablas o de los campos se suele usar un prefijo para identificar el proyecto o el servicio del que proviene o de donde se va hacer uso esa información. En el caso de las tablas no me gusta usar prefijos, pero en los campos sí (siebel_id, joomla_id, twitter_token...)

Answer (score 0):

Como el nombre de la tabla contiene espacios, debes tener cuidado al usarlo en consultas a la base de datos. Tendrás que entrecomillarlo con backticks (tildes inversas).

```
SELECT * FROM `datos de artista` ORDER BY IDart
```

Aunque es posible dar nombres que incluyan espacios a las tablas, no es nada recomendable, como estás viendo por las otras respuestas que te estánd dando.

Es preferible encontrar una palabra que defina bien lo que contiene la tabla. Y normalmente usaremos el carácter guión bajo en nombres de tablas que impliquen una relación.